# Error while accessing 127.0.0.1 through IE

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, localhost

On some machine I can access the file://127.0.0.1/test/t.htm through IE but on some machine I got error.
However if I access it through Run command it opens in IE on both machines.

[image: Working]

[image: error]

Comment: Can you access \\127.0.0.1\test\t.html` in Explorer or PowerShell? I expect the share doesn't exist (or you don't have permissions to access files through it, or you don't have permissions on the files/folders accessed via the share).

Comment: off topic; but check "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" under internet options

Comment: @AndersK. I have checked "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" but still got the same error.

Comment: @Richard file is present and accessible through Explorer.

Comment: Is protected mode enabled for Local Intranet zone (Internet Options | Security)? If enabled IE will run at Low integrity level? This might be blocking file access (this seems to be the case here where I do have that option enabled).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `127.0.0.1` to trusted sites helps:

Go to Internet Options
Click *Security* tab
Click *Trusted Sites* then *Sites* button
in *Add this website to the zone:* enter `http://127.0.0.1`
Uncheck Require https check at the bottom then click *Add*